# Xpath's "contains" doesn't work in Flutter/Dart

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xpath

Following example

```
import 'package:xml/xpath.dart';

....

print(MPD_xml.xpath("//Representation[contains(@mimeType,'audio')]/BaseURL").first.innerText);
```

gives always error

```
Unhandled exception:
XPathParserException: end of input expected at 1:17
#0      _cache.<anonymous closure> (package:xml/xpath.dart:21:5)
#1      XmlCache.[] (package:xml/src/xml/utils/cache.dart:14:29)
#2      XPathExtension.xpath (package:xml/xpath.dart:14:55)
#3      get_fb_vid (package:vidhare/retrdat.dart:40:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (package:vidhare/retrdat.dart:80:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

- 1:17 is where 'contains' start.
- Docs says xml/xpath.dart is xpath 1.0. Something to do with that?

Comment: It is a legit XPath 1.0 function: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains

Comment: I am not familiar with the package but https://pub.dev/packages/xml says "Querying the DOM using a subset of XPath.".

Comment: `contains` is not a currently supported function, feel free to file a bug and/or pull request on https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the latest development version of the [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package on GitHub:

```yaml
dependencies:
  xml:
    git: https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml
```

The library now supports all XPath 1.0 functions and is more aligned with the official standard. Queries like the one in this question are now fully supported:

```dart
final xml = XmlDocument.parse(booksXml);
final result = xml.xpath('//book[contains(@id, "106")]/title');
expect(result.map((each) => each.innerText), ['Lover Birds']);
```